# Commands to remove decimal places selectively

Tags: awk

I have a list with gene IDs with numerical attributes as follows:

Input file:

```
Solyc02g080080.3.1 Solyc02g082880.2.1 0.935486990245651 0.00610864337672501
Solyc02g079533.1.1 Solyc02g082880.2.1 0.929128021921794 0.00735626670839373
Solyc02g080670.3.1 Solyc02g082880.2.1 0.973014871168575 0.00108247051974075
```

I want to remove the '.' from the first two columns, without disturbing the last two columns

Output:

```
Solyc02g080080 Solyc02g082880 0.935486990245651 0.00610864337672501
Solyc02g079533 Solyc02g082880 0.929128021921794 0.00735626670839373
Solyc02g080670 Solyc02g082880 0.973014871168575 0.00108247051974075
```

I have tried to use :
`awk -F. '{print $1}' file`

but that prints only the first column. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=2;i++) sub(/\..*/,"",$i)} 1' file
Solyc02g080080 Solyc02g082880 0.935486990245651 0.00610864337672501
Solyc02g079533 Solyc02g082880 0.929128021921794 0.00735626670839373
Solyc02g080670 Solyc02g082880 0.973014871168575 0.00108247051974075
```

Comment: Dear Ed, sometimes I have the first two columns as `4081.Solyc00g007190.2.1 4081.Solyc12g099790.1.1 ` How should I change the code then ?

Comment: idk, depends what you want the output to be. It's important when you post a question for the sample input and expected output you provide to be truly representative of your real data. Ask a followup question with a better example to get help.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{
  sub(/\..*/, "", $1)
  sub(/\..*/, "", $2)
  print
}' input.file
```

As a side effect it collapses repeated separators into one. For example,

```
Solyc02g080080.3.1 Solyc02g082880.2.1  0.935486990245651   0.00610864337672501
```

will be

```
Solyc02g080080 Solyc02g082880 0.935486990245651 0.00610864337672501
```